# SQLAlchemy cannot autoload an mssql temporary table

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I'm not able to connect to temporary tables created on an SQL server using SQLAlchemy.

I connect to the server:

```
engine = create_engine(URL, poolclass=StaticPool)
```

I fill a temporary table with data from a pandas dataframe:

```
df_tmp.to_sql('#table_test', con=engine)
```

The table exists on the server:

```
res = engine.execute('SELECT * FROM tempdb..#table_test')
print(res)
```

which returns a list of tuples of my data. But then when I try to make an SQLAlchemy table it fails with a `NoSuchTableError`:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table
metadata = MetaData(engine)
metadata.create_all()
table = Table('#table_test', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
```

I also tried this, which gives the same error:

```
table = Table('tempdb..#table_test', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
```

And I also tried creating a blank table with an SQL command, which gives the same error when I try to read it with SQLAlchemy:

```
engine.execute('CREATE TABLE #table_test (id_number INT, name TEXT)')
```

Does SQLAlchemy support temporary tables? If so what is going wrong here? I'd like to have the temporary table as an sqlalchemy.schema.Table object if possible, as then it fits with all my other code.

Comment: Do you have any better luck of you use a global temporary table (`##table_test`) instead of a local one (`#table_test`)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. No, it gives the same error in both cases.

Comment: Temporary tables are deleted when the connection that created them terminates. If you create a connection and pass that to `df.to_sql()`, then use that connection with SQLAlchemy, you may have better luck.  My guess is that the bare `Select` works because of connection caching, but the `Table` call fails because it makes a new connection.

Comment: My understanding is that StaticPool fixes that issue. There is only ever a single connection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(re: comments to the question)

Actually, it is a limitation of the current mechanism by which SQLAlchemy's `mssql` dialect checks for the existence of a table. It queries `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` for the current catalog (database), and `#temp` tables do not appear in that view. They do appear — after a fashion, and in a not-particularly-helpful way — if we `USE tempdb` and then query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` from there.

For now, I have created a GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5506) to see if we can improve on this.

**Update 2020-09-01**

The changes for the above GitHub issue have been merged into SQLAlchemy's master branch and will be included in version 1.4. If you want to take advantage of this feature before 1.4 is officially released you can install SQLAlchemy via

pip install git+https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy.git